# I am trying this code in java anyone can explain the difference in the output

Tags: java, percentage

```
double a=1000+((15/100)*1000)
```

i am trying to add 15 percent to 1000.
instead of 1150.0 output is 1000.0

But when i tried

```
double a=1000+((15*1000)/100)
```

the output is 1150.0

Comment: Hey! Please share the code.

Comment: Integer division: 15/100 == 0. Note that 15.0 would introduce floating point division, and nö remainder is löst.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/int-division-why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0